# Creating my own external authentication service

Tags: c#, authentication, webapi2

I'm trying to find a full tutorial on creating your own extent authentication service. Similar to the ones you see that say "Login with Google"  or Facebook  or Twitter...  How do I create my own version  of those? Including allowing creation of "apps",  creating their app key and secret.

Maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms when looking, I'm not sure.

Ive have a need for a central login service where applications will be able to login a user and receive their information if they have sufficient permissions.

I'm using c# and web api 2 if this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Google oauth...

Comment: Let me give you a hint. you can create similar one with Identity Management 2.2 or vNext 3, you just need to add the OAuth2/JWT, here is your headstart : http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/

Comment: Thank you both, I'll start some reading

Comment: Almost five years later, I have the exact same problem, and virtually no info can be found on the net. Sigh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer (3 or 4 depending on your .Net preference) would be a good place to start. It is an open source project that supports the OAuth2 / Open ID protocols and is very well documented to show you where to plug in your app into the pipeline. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/index.html